# mvn gwt:i18n too slow

Tags: gwt, maven

We have a relatively large project. One of the modules has 30 generated GWT message bundles.
It takes 2 seconds to generate each bundle, so 2*30 = 1 minute.
I think it's because of big classpath, because the project has a lot of dependencies and they all added to gwt.
In fact, only the src/main/java is needed for the generation. Can I somehow configure the plugin's classpath? For example, the Surefire plugin has classpathDependencyExcludes and additionalClasspathElement, but there's no universal option for all plugins. Right?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.mvn.plugin}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>i18n</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <generateDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                <i18nMessagesBundles>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.SmpMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.PrepaymentFormMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.DebitorFinanceStateMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.AttributeAnalyticAccountsMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.SearchCustomerAccountsMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.LoanRatingQualityMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.RegistrationOfContractMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.BalancesAccountTurnoverMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.RegistrationClientAccountsMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.PackTermsDialogMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.OtherLoansMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.RatingQualityControlMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.ActualDebitorPacksTableMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.RegCredDecisionMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.PaymentGrafsMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.RestructuringRegistrationMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.CancelFinishContractAccountingMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.CompletionOfContractAccountingMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.PackInfoMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.RenewalRegistrationMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.ReserveLoanAccountMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.RatingWithDeprecMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.ReserveLoanAccaOrderMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.LoanAccountAttributesMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.EkkEndorsementsMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.ReportHeadingsMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.DocumentDetailsMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.ContractChoiceMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.ZvaWObspRaspPrintListMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>ru.sbrf.iask.client.i18n.TransmitToProcessAlkLimitsMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                </i18nMessagesBundles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: gwt compilation is notoriously slow. 2 seconds to generate a message bundle seems correct, and thus logic would have it that if you have 30 message bundles it should probably take 1 minute.

Comment: @jonasr it's not about GWT compilation, it's I18NUtil.